# How to calibrate axis in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, axis

Hello people of the interwebs!

My question is pretty simple. I want to  change the horizontal and vertical axis scale? As you can see en the picture below I would like to have the value 1332 instead of ~ 3750 where you see a very clear blue line. How do I achieve this?

[image]

I appreciate all the help I can get!

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values on the axis are based on your data, so the best option would really be to scale the data you plot, e.g. instead of plotting:

```
plot(x,y,'b.')
```

plot something like:

```
plot(x*1332/3750,y*1332/3750,'b.') % assuming same scaling factor on both axes
```

The other option, which is not so good in my opinion, is to change the axes ticks after plotting:

```
current_xticks = get(gca,'XTick');
new_xticks = current_xticks * 1332,3750;
set(gca,'XTick',new_xticks);
current_yticks = get(gca,'YTick');
new_yticks = current_yticks * 1332,3750; % assuming same scaling factor on both axes
set(gca,'YTick',new_yticks);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I used your first solution, this solved my problem! :D